# Simplifying the Einstein tensor in case of a perturbed FRW metric

Tags: physics, tensors, differential-geometry

I use the code in this thread's answer:

([Calculating Einstein tensor components in Kaluza-Klein model](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291118/calculating-einstein-tensor-components-in-kaluza-klein-model/291150?noredirect=1#comment723892_291150))
to get the Einstein tensor components of a four-dimensional Kaluza Klein model.
But instead of the diagonal matrix in that thread, I use a perturbed metric [0209156](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0209156.pdf):

$ g_{00}= a^2(t) ( 1+ 2 \phi^{(1)} + \phi^{(2)} )$

$ g_{0i}=0$

$g_{ij}= a^2(t) [( 1- 2 \psi^{(1)}- \psi^{(2)})~\delta_{ij} +  \frac{1}{2} D_{ij} \chi_{ij}^{(2)}] $,

Where:

$
 D_{ij} =\partial_i \partial_j - \frac{1}{3} \delta_{ij} \partial^k \partial_k  
$

Here is the entire code I use:

```
coordList = {t, x, w, z};
coord[i_] := coordList[[i]]

met = a[t]^2 Exp[y] {{-(1 + 2 n \[CapitalPhi][t, x, w, z, y]), 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 1 - 2 n \[CapitalPsi][t, x, w, z, y] +  n 1/2 D[Xi[t, x, w, z, y], {x, 2}] - 
      1/2 n D[Xi[t, x, w, z, y], {w, 2}] - 1/2 n D[Xi[t, x, w, z, y], {z, 2}], 
     n D[D[Xi[t, x, w, z, y], x], w], n D[D[Xi[t, x, w, z, y], x], z]}, {0, n D[D[Xi[t, x, w, z, y], x], w], 1 - 2 n \[CapitalPsi][t, x, w, z, y] + n 1/2 D[Xi[t, x, w, z, y], {x, 2}] -  1/2 n D[Xi[t, x, w, z, y], {w, 2}] -  1/2 n D[Xi[t, x, w, z, y], {z, 2}], 
     n D[D[Xi[t, x, w, z, y], w], z]},{0, n D[D[Xi[t, x, w, z, y], x], z],n D[D[Xi[t, x, w, z, y], w], z],  1 - 2 n \[CapitalPsi][t, x, w, z, y] + n 1/2 D[X[t, x, w, z, y], {x, 2}] - 
      1/2 n D[Xi[t, x, w, z, y], {w, 2}] -1/2 n D[Xi[t, x, w, z, y], {z, 2}]}}; 

 invmetric = Inverse@metric;

m[a_, b_] := metric[[a, b]];

im[a_, b_] := invmetric[[a, b]];

d[a_, f_] := D[f, coord[a]];

dDel[b_, f_] := covd[f, coord[b]];

covd[0, x_] := 0;

d4[f_] := D[f, y]

term1[a_, b_] := dDel[b, d[a, f[t, y]]]/f[t, y];

term2[a_, b_] := d4[f[t, y]] d4[m[a, b]]/f[t, y];

term3[a_, b_] := -d4[d4[m[a, b]]];

term4[a_, b_, g_, d_] := im[g, d] (d4[m[a, g] d4[m[b, d]]]);

term5[a_, b_, g_, d_] := -im[g, d] (d4[m[g, d] d4[m[a, b]]])/2;

term6[a_, b_, g_, d_] := 
  m[a, b] (d4[im[g, d]] d4[m[g, d]] + (im[g, d] d4[m[g, d]])^2)/4;

ein[a_, b_] := -(term1[a, b] + term2[a, b] + term3[a, b] + 
       Sum[term4[a, b, g, d] + term5[a, b, g, d] +
```

Where n is the order of perturbation. The problem now the output is huge. How to linearize such output by Series[Exp[n], {n,0,1}], and how to divide it to first order and second order perturbation terms like for instance in [0209156](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0209156.pdf) Equations (30-40)

**Edit**

Here is an example of a code calculating Einstein tensor from the christoffel symbols, where it uses Series[--, {n,0,1}] for linearizton. And I do not get if it can divide the first order and second order perturbation terms. The idea I can not use this code because I substitute directly by the metric to the Einstein tensor equation. So this code needs to be modified for my calculation.

```
    x = {t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]};
    met ={};
    metI=Inverse[met];
    
     Chrest = 
      ParallelTable[
       Normal[Series[
         1/2 (Sum[
            metI[[i, 
              p]] (D[met[[p, j]], x[[k]]] + D[met[[k, p]], x[[j]]] - 
               D[met[[j, k]], x[[p]]]), {p, 1, 4}]), {n, 0, 1}]], {i,1,4}, {j, 1, 4}, {k, 1, 4}];
    
    Reim = ParallelTable[
       Normal[Series[
         D[Chrest[[i, l, j]], x[[k]]] - D[Chrest[[i, k, j]], x[[l]]] + 
          Sum[Chrest[[i, k, m]] Chrest[[m, l, j]], {m, 1, 4}] - 
          Sum[Chrest[[i, l, m]] Chrest[[m, k, j]], {m, 1, 4}], {n, 0, 
          1}]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}, {k, 1, 4}, {l, 1, 4}];
    
     Ricci =  ParallelTable[
       Normal[Series[Sum[Reim[[m, i, m, j]], {m, 1, 4}], {n, 0, 1}]], {i,1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}];
    
    RScal =  Normal[Series[
        Sum[Sum[metI[[i, j]] Ricci[[i, j]], {i, 1, 4}], {j, 1, 4}], {n,0,1}]];
    
     Eins =   ParallelTable[
       Normal[Series[
         Ricci[[i, j]] - 1/2 met[[i, j]] RScal, {n, 0, 1}]], {i, 1, 
        4}, {j, 1, 4}];
    
EinsUD = ParallelTable[
       Normal[Series[
         Sum[metI[[p, i]] Eins[[p, j]], {p, 1, 4}], {n, 0, 1}]], {i, 1, 
        4}, {j, 1, 4}];
    
  For[i = 1, i < 5, i++, For[j = 1, j < 5, j++,
       Eins = 
        ReplacePart[
         Eins, {i, j} -> 
          Normal[Normal[
            Series[Ricci[[i, j]] - 1/2 met[[i, j]] RScal, {n,0,1}]]]]]];
```

Comment: This might be a good time to download and learn xAct, since they incorporate xPert.m which handles perturbation theory for tensors. Maybe start by going to their site and looking at one of the xPert example notebooks to get an idea if this will meet your needs.

Comment: xAct seems to me to be the most popular option for tensor calculations with mathematica. Other options (that might have more bugs, to be expected particularly with the newer ones) can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_software#Software_for_use_with_Mathematica. I personally prefer to use xAct but I have not really experimented with the options in that list.

Comment: I mean a code with no extra MA packages, like the code in the question edit, where it calculates  Einstein tensor from the christoffel symbols and make linearization.

Comment: In the code you posted, you use Series[expr,{n,0,1}]. If you check the documentation, this mean expand in n around the value n=0. But nothing in expr depends on n, so this won't do anything. Series is normally used for expanding around a scalar or a list of scalar variables, not matrices. If you want to compute Christoffel symbols, Riemann tensors, etc. from a metric, without using a package, you might find this post useful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/how-to-calculate-scalar-curvature-ricci-tensor-and-christoffel-symbols-in-mathe/8908#8908

Comment: @jdp. Hi, the metric in `met` depends on `n` which is the order of perturbation.

Comment: Okay, but Series is doing a Taylor series expansion around "n", which generally implies n is a continuous function, not an integer value describing the order of perturbation. Try taking "met" and evaluating it inside Series[met,{n,0,2}. Is the result what you expect for n = 0,1,2? Or is it something you'd expect for n being a floating point value? What series will do is expand around n=0, assuming n is continuous, for infinitesimal values of n. But n is an integer, so the results won't be valid. To do what you want, you need

Comment: ..Series[$g_{\mu\nu},g_{\mu\nu}$(0),n], where the second argument is the unperturbed metric and n is the order. But this isn't supported - only scalar variables are supported by Series.